# error coming while compare two textbox values using java netbeans

Tags: java

When compare two values in Jtextfield it is coming error when space also including it is showing correct. But without using it is *showing error*. for example in *JTextfield1* it is "***abcd***" when in *JTextfield2* "***abcd*** " to show the message **correct** else it is showing error.

But I want to show if JTextfield1 is showing is  "abcd" and same in jTextfield2 also same as "abcd" then show  the message correct else it is false in jLabel.

my code is as follows

```
 private void jTextField2KeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:


    if (jTextField1.getText().equals(jTextField2.getText()))
    {
        jLabel1.setText("sucess");
    }
    else
    {
       jLabel1.setText("fail");

  }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when space also including it is showing correct.

Use this to avoid spaces

```
if (jTextField1.getText().trim().equals(jTextField2.getText().trim()))
```

From the doc [public String trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim())

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace
>   omitted. If this String object represents an empty character sequence,
>   or the first and last characters of character sequence represented by
>   this String object both have codes greater than '\u0020' (the space
>   character), then a reference to this String object is returned.
>
> Otherwise, if there is no character with a code greater than '\u0020'
>   in the string, then a new String object representing an empty string
>   is created and returned.

Comment: no it is still showing same error which i asked here it is need same space or it is showing error in Jlabel

Comment: @user5840896, Your question is unclear to me. But `trim()` will omit leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: your code is correct under Jbutton click but i have updated. Based on JTextfield must auto tell about the error message that I mentioned there

Comment: Sorry! I didn't understand your question clearly. Tell me what you want exactly. Your question is needed not the code. @user5840896

Comment: my question is if I entered a user id (for example userid is "abcd") and if I entered same in re enter user id box it must show it is correct else the message will show "not matching" . These must happen without using Jbutton.